# How to create combinations of cell values separated by delimiter in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a small requirement in excel.

I have two columns with multiple values separated by delimiter. I need to create combinations as below in column3. Instead of doing this manually can we achieive this using any excel formula?? Please suggest

[image]

Comment: `=TEXTJOIN("|",,FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(A2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")&","&TRANSPOSE(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(B2,",","</s><s>")&"</s></t>","//s")))`

Comment: Thank you Ben..I am using Excel 2016 so TEXTJOIN function is not available ...is there any other formula that I can use ..pls suggest ..

Answer (score 0):

So did this with text functions assuming that it is only ever 2 characters in each cell. If you want more then you can expand...

```
=LEFT(A1,1)&","&LEFT(B1,1)&"|"&LEFT(A1,1)&","&RIGHT(B1,1)&"|"&RIGHT(A1,1)&","&LEFT(B1,1)&"|"&RIGHT(A1,1)&","&RIGHT(B1,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Mike,Yes no of characters will vary

Comment: @VishnuVardhanReddy So expand - I have shown you a method…